# AC regime: Serial connection of ideal current generator and impedance and Parallel connection of ideal voltage source and impedance

Tags: ac, impedance, current-source, voltage-source

I have the following two scenarios in the AC regime:

1. **Serial connection of ideal current generator and impedance**

[image]

2. **Parallel connection of ideal voltage source and impedance**

[image]

1. When we have the first scenario in a circuit, and we are using one of the methods (**Potential of nodes method**, **Method of contour currents**), to find potentials and currents, do we change the serial connection of ideal current generator and impedance by only with ideal current generator? In other words, does the first scenario becomes (**Z** is annulled):

[image]?

But, if are asked to find, for example, active power over impedance **Z**, we can't annulle it.

How do we know when to annulle **Z** and when not to?

2. What happens in the second scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, with the positions of Z in each scenario, neither the output current nor the output voltage is affected by the presense of that impedance Z. If you are tasked with finding the power dissipated by Z then treat that as a seperate circuit; you know the current or the voltage so you can calculate power.

Comment: Can we annulle Z when we aren't finding power (in the first scenario)? Can we annulle it in the second scenario?

Comment: In scenario 1 Z is annulled to 0 ohms. In scenario 2 it is annulled to an open circuit.

Comment: When we need to find power over Z, we can't annulle it, right?

Comment: You can't annull Z if you wish to calculate its power dissipation.

Comment: So, it is annulled when finding every other parameter in a circuit that is not power, right?

Comment: I'll repeat what I said in my answer: In both cases, with the positions of Z in each scenario, neither the output current nor the output voltage is affected by the presense of that impedance Z.

Comment: You've uploaded and deleted various snippets of this homework question over the last 2 days. Why don't you upload the *complete* question, with all the given parameter values, along with your best attempt?